# DBIC- select specific columns in "prefetch" while maintaining has_many relationship

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I have two tables with 'Artist' `has_many` 'CD' .

I want to fetch 'artist' and 'CDs' and use HashRefInflator to get something like (JSON format)
I use 'HashRefInflator'.

```
     [ {
        
        "artist_name": "Dummy",
        "artist_id": "1",
            "cds": [{
            "cd_id": "1,
            "cd_desc": "Dummy",
            }],
         },
      ]
```

When I use

```
$schema->resultset('Artist')->search({}, 
                                       {
                                         prefetch => 'cds',
                                       });
```

I get result with "EXTRA" column from CD table. I want to be able to select only specific column from 'CD'.

When I use

```
$schema->resultset('Artist')->search({}, 
                                     {'+select' => [ 'columns I need' ],
                                      '+as' => [ 'col names' ],
                                     });
```

I get 'columns i need' merged with main columns instead of a hierarchy.

```
      [ {
        "artist_name": "Dummy",
        "artist_id": "1",
        "cds": []
        **"cd_id": "1,
        "cd_desc": "Dummy",**
      
   
         },
        ]
```

How can I prefetch specific columns from related table while maintaining the hierarchical structure?

Edit: I am sorry if I was not very clear. The problem here with `join` and `+columns` / `+select` is that it does not preserve the hierarchical data structure.

The 'cds' should be an array of objects within 'Artist' object.Instead it gets joined at Artist level.
I could not use "collapse" as I have an older version of DBIx::Class. I would try to install a later version and check.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DBIx-Class prefetch usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786540/dbix-class-prefetch-usage)

Answer (score 1):

Use join instead of prefetch:

```
$schema->resultset('Artist')->search(
    {},
    {
        join         => ['cds'],
        '+select'    => ['cd.desc'],
        result_class => 'DBIx::Class::ResultClass::HashRefInflator'
    }
);
```

Comment: prefetch is just join + columns. It's recommended to use columns instead of select + as because it's easier to use and harder to get wrong.

Comment: "How can I prefetch specific columns from related table while maintaining the hierarchical structure. ?" I think the user wants only some columns from the join. Prefetch will get all of them. edit: I have to research. Did not know about columns.

Comment: This leads to the problem where 'cds' => [] is empty and the columns from 'CD' table appear at a higher level as shown in the second JSON example.

Comment: If you are trying to join on a many to many, you will need to use +columns, and specify the matching DBIC space. This is shown in a good example at https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class::ResultSet#prefetch

Answer (score 0):

You'll need `DBIx::Class` version 0.08250 or later which supports the [`collapse` result set attribute](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx%3a%3aClass%3a%3aResultSet#collapse):

```
my $rs = $schema->resultset('Artist')->search({}, {
    '+columns' => [ qw/ cds.col1 cds.col2 / ],
    join       => 'cds',
    collapse   => 1,
});
```